# CRTP vs name hiding for static polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

How does using the Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) differ from name hiding to achieve static polymorphism?

For example, here is a simple example demonstrating static polymorphism using the CRTP and name hiding:

```
template <typename T>
struct BaseCRTP {
    void foo() { 
        static_cast<T*>(this)->foo(); 
    }

    void bar() { 
        std::cout << "bar from Base" << std::endl; 
    }
};

struct DerivedCRTP : public BaseCRTP<DerivedCRTP> {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo from Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct BaseNH {
    void foo() {}

    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar from Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct DerivedNH : public BaseNH {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo from Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void useCRTP(BaseCRTP<T>& b) {
    b.foo();
    b.bar();
}

template <typename T>
void useNH(T b) {
    b.foo();
    b.bar();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DerivedCRTP instance_crtp; // "foo from Derived"
    DerivedNH instance_nm; // "bar from Base"
    useCRTP(instance_crtp); // "foo from Derived"
    useNH(instance_nm); // "bar from Base"
    return 0;
}
```

To clarify, this isn't a question about mechanics, rather of behaviour and use.

Comment: The `useCRTP` function has little UB. You need to pass by reference, or use the most derived type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case where a base class method calls some other method.

With CRTP the called method can be overridden.

With name hiding there is no override mechanism.

---

Example.
This code uses CRTP for static polymorphism where the `kind` method is overridden in the derived class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< class Derived >
class Animal
{
public:
    auto self() const
        -> Derived const&
    { return static_cast<Derived const&>( *this ); }

    auto kind() const -> char const* { return "Animal"; }
    void identify() const { cout << "I'm a " << self().kind() << "." << endl; }
};

class Dog
    : public Animal< Dog >
{
public:
    auto kind() const -> char const* { return "Dog"; }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    Dog().identify();
}
```